# selectChannel command is not working on the Google Assistant

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home, google-smart-home

I'm trying to add a select channel trait.
what I did was that I followed the [docs](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/traits/channel),

1- Add the ATTRIBUTES to the device I want to apply this feature on, for example, a TV device type

2- I guess we are all done as every other command works with my code

What I actually did was the following to the device database in Firestore

[image: Screen Shot 2022-04-23 at 2 54 26 AM]

---

[image: Screen Shot 2022-04-23 at 3 00 04 AM]

then added the

```
case "action.devices.commands.selectChannel":
```

in the

```
 switch (execution.command) {}
```

code

then reloaded the device from the google home app
then when I try to call
"Change to ABC on my TV"
it says
'Sorry, I don't understand.'
and nothing appears on the logs
otherwise, everything is working perfectly,i.e setting the volume and On/Off.
what am I doing wrong, please?

**UPDATE:**
Today I tried command `"action.devices.commands.returnChannel"` and `"action.devices.commands.relativeChannel"` and they are working fine
and all three commands belongs to the same [trait](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/traits/channel)!
I've seen a lot of users complaining about this command on many sites
like the following [1](https://support.google.com/assistant/thread/147717089/unable-to-change-channel-on-tv?hl=en),[2](https://www.googlenestcommunity.com/t5/Speakers-and-Displays/Google-Nest-Hub-doesn-t-change-TV-channels/td-p/91029),
could this be related,
I'm still in debug mode, would it be fixed when I publish my app

**UPDATE #2**
I tried it today with an android phone and it works fine with selectChannel command,
previously I was testing with an iPhone with google home and google assistant apps on their latest release, and the selectChannel is the only command that didn't work there.
Hope it's just related to the debugging mode

Comment: Are you getting logs for Volume and On/Off trait perfectly fine ? If so can you share the logs for these traits and also can you share the SYNC and EXECUTE payload ?

Comment: all logs are perfectly fine with no error.
thought there is an update,
I tried it today with an android phone and it works fine with select channel,
previously I was testing with an iPhone with google home and google assistant apps on their latest update, and the select channel is the only command that didn't work there.
Hope it's just related to the debugging mode

Answer (score 0):

It is usually unexpected to have a trait / feature working on the Google Home App on Android but not on the iOS version, as their functionality is nearly identical. The accuracy on the speech to text conversion on both platforms might be different, which could be affecting the functionality. You can try out typing your request to see if that helps in any way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,
yeah, I did that already, I tried to type the order instead of saying it.
I thought it might be an error related to the application probably in the debugging mode only, haven't tried it since though